# Error in predictions$class : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, r-caret, predict, naivebayes

I am trying to use the Naive Bayes method on my own data, which predicts a diagnosis for breast cancer based upon 9 features. I'm trying to use a 70% training data and 30% testing data.

Here's my code:

```
> BCD <- read.csv("H:/BCD.csv")
>   View(BCD)
> trainIndex <- createDataPartition(BCD$Diagnosis, p=0.70, list=FALSE)
> data_train <- BCD[ trainIndex,]
> data_test <- BCD[-trainIndex,]
#train a naive bayes model
> model <- naiveBayes(Diagnosis~., data=data_train)
#make predictions
> predictions <- predict(model, data_test[,1:9])
#summarize results
> confusionMatrix(predictions$class, data_test$Diagnosis)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in predictions$class : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any idea what this means or how I can fix it?

Here's a sample of my data that will hopefully help:

```
> dput(head(BCD))
structure(list(Clump.Thickness = c(5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 8L), Uniformity.of.Cell.Size = c(1L, 
4L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 10L), Uniformity.of.Cell.Shape = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 
8L, 1L, 10L), Marginal.Adhesion = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 8L), 
    Single.Epithelial.Cell.Size = c(2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 7L), 
    Bare.Nuclei = c(1L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 10L), Bland.Chromatin = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L), Normal.Nucleoli = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 
    1L, 7L), Mitoses = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Diagnosis = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("Clump.Thickness", "Uniformity.of.Cell.Size", 
"Uniformity.of.Cell.Shape", "Marginal.Adhesion", "Single.Epithelial.Cell.Size", 
"Bare.Nuclei", "Bland.Chromatin", "Normal.Nucleoli", "Mitoses", 
"Diagnosis"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in this in any means, but in the example you gave the object 'predictions' is empty.

Comment: So the error must be with the `predict(model, data_test[,1:9])` then?

Comment: It seems like your predictions aren't generated like you expect, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
BCD$Diagnosis = as.factor(BCD$Diagnosis)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(BCD$Diagnosis, p=0.70, list=FALSE)
data_train <- BCD[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- BCD[-trainIndex,]
#train a naive bayes model
model <- naiveBayes(Diagnosis~., data=data_train)
#make predictions
predictions <- predict(model, data_test[,1:9])
#summarize results
confusionMatrix(predictions, data_test$Diagnosis)
```

Changes are that you have to set class feature to be factor (first line) and in the last line adjust *predictions$class* to just *predictions*

Answer (score 0):

$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

What this error really means:

The R runtime tries to do a $ operation on an object that is does not support $ behavior at all. For example, a single string or integer. See this R terminal output:

```
> s="Gucci Mane"
> s$artistName
Error in s$artistName : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> t=list(artistName="Gucci Mane", realName="Radric Davis")
> t$artistName
[1] "Gucci Mane"
```

If you got this error, you most likely did some lookup operation that returned the wrong object.

What makes this error super confusing:

- you would expect an error like "property s$artistName not found". But the runtime did not even attempt to resolve the $. It saw that the object in question does not support $ operations at all, and reports that as an error.
- "atomic" in the entire developer world means "an operation that will never be interrupted by a thread or process context switch", but in R, oh joy, it means something like "primitive datatype that does not support collection behavior"
- some help topics you find with google suggest this error has something to do with recursion, which is nonsense. At best your recursion returned the wrong thing.

@developers of the R language, feature request: error messages with a -some- context of what you are doing wrong and where, would be huge time saver!

Answer (score -1):

I ended up figuring this out by doing it this way:

I changed this: `> predictions <- predict(model, data_test[,1:9])`
 to this: `> predictions <- predict(model, data_test[,1:10, -10])`

and then just saved my results to a csv file and viewed them that way.